# Suggestions for a timer for a shop heater

Tags: wiring

I have a shop heater - 20A, 240V, 4000W - and need to put a timer in the circuit. Any suggestions?

Comment: A timer controlling a suitable relay.

Comment: Do you want it to turn on and off at set times of day, or run for a set period of time then turn off?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. Trendy pushbutton timers require neutral, and you don't have it. **Wait.  You're old-school, and you want to use an Intermatic wind-up timer where the energy comes from YOU? Oh yes, that'll work just fine!**

No [image] . . . 
Yes [image]

In fact, that's exactly what I did with a water heater.   Now, the timer *might* be rated for the amperage.  But I didn't take any chances; I used a 240V relay.

Mind you, I used a relay intended for an air conditioning compressor, and that is not Code legal, because that relay was not application-listed for a water heater.  But if you can find a relay that is listed for your purpose, or a general-purpose type like a RiB, then you're all set.

There are also the Aube relays *with transformers built-in*, which provide 24V pilot voltage, so you can do the wiring from relay to timer with low-voltage thermostat wire.

And if you're thinking "24V! That means I could use any 24V thermostat, even the Nest!" you're almost right.  Depending on the model, Aube's transformer may be too little to power the Nest, but you could use separate transformer + relay, or a relay-transformer that's a little bigger.  I've even seen transformer+relays that mount on junction box lids.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking the Intermatic would work but I am not looking to have it on a cycle, but more like the push button thing - 10 minutes, 15 minutes etc. - while I am out in the garage. So I am not sure the Intermatic would work. I may be resigned to a switch (like old school on/off).

Comment: @Muzza1965 Intermatic makes a variety of timers.  You are thinking of their 24-hour or 7-day motorized time-of-day/time-of-week timers that cost $200-ish.   I am referring to their simple knob-twist rundown timers that cost under $20.  Used in bathroom fans before people started insisting on pushbuttons (they no longer have wrists, apparently).  Edited.

Comment: i think that might be it - Thanks!

Comment: Anything that requires turning a knob (or almost anything else) right or left seems completely foreign to some people these days. That said, I don't mind the push button controller...in the bathroom. Just not for this application where I need to just, keep it simple with function over form.